# How to pass html element(table) dynamically to angular directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, export-to-csv

I have html tables which are rendered using ng-repeat, i have to export data of that tables into csv file, I found one directive which does it, it works well for one table and did not works properly when there are multiple tables which are using same directive. When i click on export button then the last processed html table is exported not the required one. Bellow i given my HTML code. Here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6Vb64xxomhCHXg7GE1R?p=preview)

```
           <label for="state" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="tag">Select territory:</span></label>
                   <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <select ng-model="rtype" ng-options="reportName for (reportName, reportType) in reportTypeOptions" class="form-control" id="rtype"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>   

            <div class="col-sm-9 " style="margin-top: 30px;" ng-show="userLocations.stateWise">
                <a ng-click='csv.generate($event, filename() + ".csv", t1)' href=''><button class="btn btn-default export-btn">Export</button></a>
                <table id="t1" ng-table="tableParams1" show-filter="false" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" ng-show="rtype === 'state'" export-csv='csv'> 
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in userLocations.stateWise">
                        <td data-title="'Sr No.'" style="width:3%;">{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                        <td data-title="'State'" style="width:5%;">{{ key }} </td>
                        <td data-title="'Total Users'" style="width:7%;">{{ value }} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="t2" ng-table="tableParams2" show-filter="false" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" ng-show="rtype === 'dist'" export-csv='csv'> 
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in userLocations.districtWise">
                        <td data-title="'Sr No.'" style="width:3%;" style="width:3%;">{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                        <td data-title="'State'" style="width:5%;">{{ value.userLocation.state }} </td>
                        <td data-title="'District'" style="width:7%;">{{ value.userLocation.district }} </td>
                        <td data-title="'Total Users'" style="width:7%;">{{ value.totalUsers }} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="t3" ng-table="tableParams3" show-filter="false" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" ng-show="rtype === 'pin'" export-csv='csv'> 
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in userLocations.pincodeWise">
                        <td data-title="'Sr No.'" style="width:3%;" style="width:3%;">{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                        <td data-title="'State'" style="width:5%;">{{ value.userLocation.state }} </td>
                        <td data-title="'District'" style="width:7%;">{{ value.userLocation.district }} </td>
                        <td data-title="'Pincode'" style="width:7%;">{{ value.userLocation.pincode }} </td>
                        <td data-title="'Total Users'" style="width:7%;">{{ value.totalUsers }} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div> 
    ` // Angular directive code toexport table 
    app.directive('exportCsv', ['$parse', '$timeout', 'ngTableEventsChannel', function ($parse, $timeout, ngTableEventsChannel) {
      var delimiter = ',';
      var header = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,';
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: false,
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var data = '';
             if (attrs.delimiter) { delimiter = attrs.delimiter; }
              function stringify(str) {
                return '"' +
                  str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s*\s$/, '') 
                     .replace(/"/g,'""') + '"';
              }
              function parseTable() {
                data = '';
                var rows = element.find('tr');
                angular.forEach(rows, function(row, i) {
                  var tr = angular.element(row),
                    tds = tr.find('th'),
                    rowData = '';
                  if (tr.hasClass('ng-table-filters')) {
                    return;
                  }
                  if (tds.length === 0) {
                    tds = tr.find('td');
                  }
                  if (i !== 1) {
                    angular.forEach(tds, function(td) {
                      rowData += stringify(angular.element(td).text()) + Array.apply(null, Array(td.colSpan)).map(function () { return delimiter; }).join('');
                    });
                    rowData = rowData.slice(0, rowData.length - 1); 
                  }
                  data += rowData + '\n';
                });
                data = 'sep=' + delimiter + '\n' + data;
              }
              function download(dataUri, filename, scope) {
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.style.display = 'none';
                link.href = dataUri;
                link.download = filename;
                link.target = '_blank';
                 $timeout(function () {
                  try {
                    document.body.appendChild(link);
                    link.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(link);
                  }
                  catch(err) {
                    if (scope.logError) {
                      scope.logError('NG Table Export Error saving file on client.');
                    }
                    throw(err);
                  }
                }, 0, false);
              }
// csv var for calling its method
              var csv = {
                generate: function(event, filename, table) {
                  var isNgTable = attrs.ngTable,
                    table = table || scope.$parent.tableParams,
                    settings = table ? table.settings() : {},
                    cnt = table ? table.count() : {},
                    total = table ? settings.total : {};
                  if (isNgTable && cnt < total) {
                    var $off = ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterReloadData(function () {
                      $off();
                      $timeout(function () {
                        parseTable();
                        table.count(cnt);
                        table.reload();
                        download(header + encodeURIComponent(data), filename, scope);
                      }, 1000, false);
                    });
                    table.count(Infinity);
                    table.reload();
                  } else {
                    parseTable();
                    download(header + encodeURIComponent(data), filename);
                  }
                }
              };
              $parse(attrs.exportCsv).assign(scope.$parent, csv);
          }
      };
    }]);`

How to give element to directive if element occurs more than once.
```

Comment: Can you provide a working demo? it will be easier to help if you do.

Comment: Hi @MohammadWalid here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6Vb64xxomhCHXg7GE1R?p=preview) for given problem, if you know any other way to export ng-table will be appreciated